# Where are python operators defined?

Tags: python, operators

Where are the python operators like +, -, * defined? I am a newbie, so please give a detailed answer to this question.

Comment: inside your interpretor enter help(1) and look the output  -__add__(self, val) for exemple is defined fpr '+' etc

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: @user1438644 Okay, so the methods of the int class are responsible.

Comment: Operators *behave* differently depending on the operands. The docs - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html - explain the results of using an operator with different types.

Comment: @wwii Thanks!! Please answer this question in detail.https://stackoverflow.com/q/61835719/13469230

Comment: simply put, if you need to make addition between two class's instance of your choice, you need to define the method" __add_(self, value) for that class...we are saying that you overload operator. look at the provided link by @Kenny...also note that how '+' will do its job will be exactly the business done by the code inside '__add__(self, value)' and so on

Comment: I'm afraid this question is probably off-topic but that's just my opinion. Please always reasearch the documentation before asking a question like this. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: @user1438644 Thanks!! Please answer this question in great detail. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61835719/13469230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every Python class has built-in methods (can be recognized by the "__" in the beginning and end of their name) that define their behavior. for example, when using `print()` on an object, the built-in `__str__` function is called, and it is different for every class.
you can override these functions with your own implementations.

here is a class named `CarCollection`:

```
class CarCollection():
    def __init__(self, car_list):
        self.cars_in_collection = car_list
```

now, say for example you want to add two collections together. using the "+" between two instances of this class will raise `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'instance'`, so in order to add two collections together you need to override the `__add__` function:

```
    def __add__(self, other_car_collection):
        return self.cars_in_collection + other.cars_in_collection
```

now when you add two collections together and print the result it will look like this:

```
first_collection = CarCollection(["subaru", "ferrari"])
second_collection = CarCollection(["fiat", "renault"])
print(second_collection + first_collection)
```

output: `subaru, ferrari, fiat, renault`